# Setting up a dict in the constructor (python)

Tags: python, class, dictionary, constructor

Hey I am a python rookie and I am trying to setup a dict in the constructor of a class how ever, whenever I try to access an element, it returns None. Here is my code

```
class GoogleApp:

  def __init__(self, path):
    self.name = "Google App"
    self.description = "Creates an new google app project."
    self.title = None
    self.path = path
    self.pre_defined_macros = {
      '_NAME': self.name , 
      '_DESCRIPTION': self.description,
      '_TITLE': "Shoutout",
      '_BASE_PATH': self.path,
      '_PATH': lambda: os.path.join(self.path, self.title)
    }
```

Now whenever I try to access self.pre_defined_macros['_TITLE'] from some other method it returns None.

Comment: underscore implies private variable. what happens when you give without an underscore.

Comment: @ignacio, yes are correct. I am way to sleepy for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post sample code?

I ask this because I'm not sure what you are trying to do. `<instance>.pre_defined_macros['_TITLE']` worked fine when I tested it.

```
>>> class GoogleApp:

  def __init__(self, path):
    self.name = "Google App"
    self.description = "Creates an new google app project."
    self.title = None
    self.path = path
    self.pre_defined_macros = {
      '_NAME': self.name , 
      '_DESCRIPTION': self.description,
      '_TITLE': "Shoutout",
      '_BASE_PATH': self.path,
      '_PATH': lambda: os.path.join(self.path, self.title)
    }


>>> f  = GoogleApp('foo')
>>> f.pre_defined_macros['_TITLE']
'Shoutout'
>>>
```

I also tried accessing `pre_defined_macros` from another method. Like so:

```
>>> class GoogleApp:
    def __init__(self, path):
        # Your original code here.
    def get_title(self):
        return self.pre_defined_macros['_TITLE']


>>> f  = GoogleApp('foo')
>>> f.get_title()
'Shoutout'
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry! Actually '_TITLE': "Shoutout"

Comment: Sorry! Actually '_TITLE': "Shoutout" worked however it's returning None when '_TITLE' = self.title , just like I am having the same problem with '_DESCRIPTION' and '_NAME'

Answer (score 0):

Aah ... Got it!

Actually I've set

```
self.title = None
```

So while creating the dictionary

```
'_TITLE': self.title
```

None is the value for '_TITLE'

Lack of concentration !!